# How to overwrite this code in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code I have where it is suppose to display the number within the textbox when the "Add" button is clicked on `$('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer);`. But I also have a line of code where it triggers the function for when a (btn 'button') is clicked on.

```
 function addwindow(numberAnswer, gridValues, btn) { 
    $('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer);
    $('#btn'+gridValues).trigger('click');       
 }
```

Because of the trigger it triggers this function `$('.gridBtns').on('click', function()`. In this function is this line of code

```
$('.answertxt', context).val(context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length > 0 ? context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length : '');,
```

This line of code checks for how many buttons were turned on when the gridBtn is clicked and displays the number in the textbox. But the line of code above is overwriting the `$('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer);` in the addwindow() function.

EXAMPLE:

If there were 2 '#btns' which were turned on but then I click on the "Add" button to add the number displayed under the "Number of Answers" column (lets say this number is 1), then it should display number 1 in the textbox by this code taking affect `$('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer);`, but instead it is displaying number 2, because this code is taking affect:     `$('.answertxt', context).val(context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length > 0 ? context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length : '');`

How can I get number 1 to be displayed and not number 2 to be displayed in the example above

Below is html code of textbox:

```
<input type="text" name="numberAnswer" class="numberAnswerTxt answertxt" id="mainNumberAnswerTxt" readonly="readonly" onChange="getButtons()" >
```

UPDATE:

Here is a [demo](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text14.php) of the application. Please follow the steps below:

- Step 1: When you open up the demo, click on the "Open grid" link and
  select button "7". This will display a textbox and 7 letter buttons
  underneath.
- Step 2: Select 4 letter buttons underneath of you choice. You will
  see when you turn on a letter button the textbox above counts it.
- Step 3: Now on left hand side you will see a green plus button, click
  on it and it opens up a modal window.
- Step 4: In modal window there is a search bar, type in "AAA" and
  submit search, you will see a bunch of rows appear.
- Step 5: In the first row, you see under "Number of Answer" colum that
  it contains the number 1, click on the "Add" button within this row,
  the modal window will close but there is problem which you can read
  below.

Problem:

In the "Number of Answers" textbox, it should display the number 1, but it doesn't.

Comment: Way too confusing a question. Read it back to yourself slowly and see if it makes any sense. I would suggest putting in more code (like the HTML, perhaps), and specify what it is you're trying to do (the end goal), rather than what is wrong your specific way. Answer-ers might be able to suggest a better, simpler way.

Comment: How are you calling `addwindow`?

Comment: Addwindow is called from an "Add" button which is this: `echo "<td class='addtd'><button type='button' class='add' onclick=\"parent.addwindow()\">Add</button></td></tr>";`

Comment: @user1490145: What exactly do you want to do?  You can't "overwrite" code, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Is this editted question a lot better to understand if you read the example?

Comment: Does `#mainNumberAnswerTxt` have a class of `answertxt`?

Comment: Sounds like the element with ID `#mainNumberAnswerTxt` also has a class `.answertxt`

Comment: Yes #mainNumberAnswerTxt have a class of answertxt, I will put the html code of the textbox in the question

Comment: @user1490145 that's your problem. The second thing applies to all elements with that class, including `mainNumberAnswerTxt`

Comment: @sachleen yes I want the second code to be applied to all textboxes but I don't want it to occur ahead of `$('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer);`. I want `$('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer);` to occur ahead of the 2nd code

Comment: @user1490145 can't you just remove that class from the one with the ID? seems like a simpler solution..

Comment: @sachleen No because the reason I need the class is because I want the user to be able to duplicate the textboxes so I need this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this question is quite confusing, but I think i figured out what you want:
Just add a class or attribute to the mainNumberAnswerTxt so it can be ignored by the second on click event

```
function addwindow(numberAnswer, gridValues, btn) { 
    $('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer).attr('data-ignore',true);
    $('#btn'+gridValues).trigger('click');       
}
```

and then in your $('.gridBtns').on('click', function() you simply check (don't know your exact html & js-code)

```
if(this).attr('data-ignore') != true {
    $('.answertxt', context).val(context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length > 0 ?      context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length : '');
}
```

Comment: I tried you code but same thing is happening. If I turn on 3 buttons, and then add a row where "Number of Answers" equals 1, 1 button is turned on but it still states 3 in textbox, not 1.

Comment: Ok, then could you please provide us with an example on jsfiddle ?

Comment: I have included a demo in my question, just follow the steps